# Yielding more requests if scraper was idle more than 20s

Tags: scrapy

I would like to `yield` more requests at the end of a `CrawlSpider` that uses `Rules`.
I noticed I was not able to feed more requests by doing this in the `spider_closed` method:
`self.crawler.engine.crawl(r, self)`
I noticed that this technic work in `spider_idle` method but I would like to wait to be sure that the crawl is finished before feeding more requests.

I set the setting `CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT = 30`
What would be the code to wait 20 seconds idle before triggering the process of feeding more requests?
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

If it is really important that the previous crawling has completely finished before the new crawling starts, consider running either two separate spiders or the same spider twice in a row with [different arguments](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments) that determine which URLs it crawls. See [Run Scrapy from a script](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script).

If you don’t really need for the previous crawling to finish, and you simply have URLs that should have a higher priority than other URLs for some reason, consider using request priorities instead. See the `priority` parameter of the [Request class constructor](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request).